# Creating and using a Bash script and a module in FreeRADIUS

Tags: bash, samba, freeradius, radius

I have a problem with my FreeRADIUS code.

I have a script `script_recherche_info.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

username=$1
if grep -q -w "$username" "/fichiers_radius/info.txt"; then
  exit 1 
else
  exit 0 
fi
```

I also have a module in `freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/recherche_cop51`:

```
exec recherche_cop51 {
        
        wait = yes
        program = "/fichiers_radius/script_recherche_info.sh $username"
        input_pairs = request
        output_pairs = reply
        shell_escape = yes
}
```

and I use this in the post-auth in `/sites-enabled/default`:

```
if ((recherche_cop51(%{User-Name})) {
     update reply {  
         Reply-Message := "you are authorized"}
```

I want to use the username of the user trying to connect to the wifi in module `recherche_cop51`, have the module call the script, and search in `info.txt` if the user exists or not.

How can I do that?